# Could you please tell me if the second she in this sentence sounds natural or redundant?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Could you please explain to me if the second she in this sentence sounds natural or redundant and the reason behind your answer:

> - She gets a sparkle in her eyes when **she** looks at you.

Comment: It is completely right. A clause needs a subject. She is the subject of both clauses.

Comment: It could also say **when looking at you**.

Comment: It could also say `When she looks at you, she gets a sparkle in her eyes.` or similar to what [TRomano](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tromano) said, `When looking at you, she gets a sparkle in her eyes.`

Comment: In general, please explain why you think your examples might be correct or incorrect, natural or unnatural, etc. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the correct way to express that sentence.

If you didn't include the second *she*, the verb in your *when* clause would not have a subject. If it was omitted, it would be understood but it would be incorrect.

Comment: By *understood but it would be incorrect*, what you mean is *would be understood by Anglophones as a reliable indicator of "non-native speaker".* I think it's not a mistake that native speakers would *ever* make (so it would stick out quite markedly).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: By "understood" I mean that any fluent speaker will be able to discern the meaning. I would agree that it isn't a mistake likely to be made by a native speaker, and it would most likely indicate that the person who said it is not a native speaker.

Comment: Well, I'd think any halfway advanced *learner* would be able to discern the meaning too (perhaps the OP himself might even find the incorrect version *easier*, because that's how his own language works). But the thing is there are lots of "errors" made by native speakers even when they know perfectly well they're incorrect. Perhaps *...and infallibly recognized as such* or something like that at the end of your text? (These comments are "ephemera" that may get deleted, but I'd say the point is worth making more permanently).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A learner probably would understand, but the typical benchmark is a native (or fluent) speaker. My opinion is that by saying something is incorrect, it is implicitly said that it should not be used. If something is incorrect but used by native/fluent speakers, that should be explicitly said – not the other way around.

Answer (score 11):

In a *when* clause, a **finite** verb—one which is inflected for tense, person and number—**requires** an explicit subject, so the second *she* is necessary.

It is only if you use a **non-finite** verb (in this case an *-ing* form would be acceptable) that you may omit the subject; the subject is inferred to be the  subject of the main clause to which the *when* clause is attached.

> She gets a sparkle in her eyes when looking at you.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the "looking" form is not so intense in this context.

Comment: That's basically the same, but there is a *slight* difference. "When she looks at you" can be read to mean at the moment that the looking begins, whereas "when looking at you" implies that the effect lasts until she stops looking. So, to pick things apart, it would probably make more sense to say that "she *has* a sparkle in her eyes when looking at you".